# Play Framework 2.8 - request and flash not found on view

Tags: java, web, playframework

I'm trying to get the flash data that has been passed from the controller in the view. In the Play documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaSessionFlash) it says the flash can be get like this:

```
@flash.get("success").orElse("Welcome!")
```

However, I'm getting this error when I try to compile the project

```
[error] .../edit.scala.html:4:3: not found: value flash
[error]     @flash.get("test").orElse("No flash!")
[error]      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I've also tried using `@request.flash` and it gave the same error.

How can I get the flash or request in the view for Play Framework 2.8. Am I missing some import or something like that?

Comment: Did you add the implicit flash param to the template?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Java you need to pass the request param to the template. At the top of the template file:

```
@( ... your normal params ...)(implicit request: Http.Request)
```

Now to get the flash use the request:

```
@request.flash().getOptional("test")
```

Comment: Hello @vm4, thanks for the answer. I tried doing that, but now I'm getting an error in the controller because it is expecting to pass the `request` parameter in the action result.

I`m getting this error:

```.../RecipeController.java:52:1: method render in class views.html.recipe.edit cannot be applied to given types;
[error]   required: models.Recipe,play.mvc.Http.Request
[error]   found: models.Recipe
[error]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[error]     return ok(views.html.recipe.edit.render(recipe)).flashing("danger", "Error");
```

Comment: Well you need to pass the request param to the template. Declare your controller method like this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaActions#What-is-an-Action?

Comment: Got it. I thought that using `implicit` would make not necessary to return the request explicitly in the result.